# How to use MessageFormat.format on a string with symbols { and " in Java

Tags: java, string

I am trying to use MessageFormat.format() on a string containing the symbols: {

I am fetching this string from my .properties file, as a key value pair like this:

```
helloWorldString=hello{"hello":"{0}"}
```

I would like to use the

```
MessageFormat.format(helloWorldString, "world");
```

However, this throws an error **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't parse argument number: "hello":"%s"**

I have also tried:

```
helloWorldString=hello%7B%22hello%22:%22%s%22%7D
```

to get the error: **java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '2'**

And:

```
helloWorldString=hello%7B"hello":"%s"%7D
```

which returns the error: **java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'D'**

Any help on formatting these symbols, with the %s (or an alternative String placeholder) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The ``helloWorldString=hello{"hello":"%s"}`` in the properties file, with ``String.format(helloWorldString, "world");`` works fine for me. Please post your verifiable code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out (although I could not reproduce your success with the code I originally posted) - I have amended the question to be accurate.

Comment: Check the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44014943/1069114) by @EJP. You are using a wrong format for ``MessageFormat``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your property file entry should look like this:

```
helloWorldString='{'"hello":"{0}"'}'
```

You must escape the `{`and `}`symbols which do not enclose arguments with a `'`.

From the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html):

> Within a String, a pair of single quotes can be used to quote any arbitrary characters except single quotes. For example, pattern string "'{0}'" represents string "{0}", not a FormatElement. A single quote itself must be represented by doubled single quotes '' throughout a String. For example, pattern string "'{''}'" is interpreted as a sequence of '{ (start of quoting and a left curly brace), '' (a single quote), and }' (a right curly brace and end of quoting), not '{' and '}' (quoted left and right curly braces): representing string "{'}", not "{}".

Answer (score -3):

You're making it up. Have a look at the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html). There is no `%s` feature in `MessageFormat`. If you want the result to be `"hello world"`, the property entry should be

```
helloWorldString="hello {0}"
```

Similarly you are making this up as well:

```
hello%7B%22hello%22:%22%s%22%7D
```

There is no URL-encoding feature in a .properties file, or in `MessageFormat`.

Use the documentation.